# System.IndexOutOfRangeException when checking for being in range

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, exception

I *am* checking for the index to be in range, but it's throwing a System.IndexOutOfRangeException... Theoretically the following should work:

```
for (int b = 1; b <= p.Length-2; a++)
```

but I still get a

> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>           at scred.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\CodeJam\Store Credit - Small (C-Sharp)\Program.cs:line 29

on run

Code: https://gist.github.com/mypalsminecraft/9498980 (who needs [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Y1PptWR5)?)

Comment: Exactly why you should use Linq rather than for loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like that you have done a copy&paste error:

```
for (int a = 1; a <= p.Length-2; a++)
                {
                    bool done = false;
                    for (int b = 1; b <= p.Length-2; a++)
                    {
```

should be

```
for (int a = 1; a <= p.Length-2; a++)
                {
                    bool done = false;
                    for (int b = 1; b <= p.Length-2; b++)
                    {
```

instead. Notice the `b++` instead of the `a++`.

Comment: Oh, that wasn't a copy&paste error, that was a typing derp.